# How to represent math iteration and mapping issue

Tags: functions

I want to translate a function into math notations.

I have a number `X = 1000` and I have a list of numbers `A = [200,300,50,50,400,500,700]` and list of letters `B = [AA,BB,CC,DD,EE,FF,GG]` which is map for list `A`

I iterate over the `A` and compare if the first element of list `A` is larger than `X`, then in second iteration, I compare if the sum of first and second element are larger than `X` and repeat the process unti the sum of `n` element is larger than `X`. I took the number of iteration (index) where the condition was meet and return the corresponding element from list `B`.

**pseudo function**

```
function F(X,A,B) {
  for index in A; do:
    if sum(A[index0:index]) > X:
      return B[index]
}
```

in this example, `F(X,A,B)` will return `FF`

Can someone please help me to put this function in mathematical notations or guide me on where I can learn how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using typical conventions like subscripts for the mathematics equivalent of array indexing, you can write the desired value of $\mathtt{index}$, which I'll call $i_1$, as follows:

$$
i_1 = \min_n \left(\sum_{i = i_0}^n A_i > X\right)
$$

(where I've written $i_0$ for your $\mathtt{index0}$ - which I presume is $0$ if you are coding in python). In words the above says $i_0$ is the least $n$ such that the sum of the $A_i$ for $i$ from $i_0$ to $n$ exceeds $X$. The final result is then $B_{i_1}$.

By the way, I think the result is actually $\mathtt{FF}$ in your example, because $200 + 300 + 50 + 50 + 400 = 1000$, so you have to carry on to $n = 5$ to exceed $1000$.

As to where to learn more, Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming* is the bible, for many people, but there are lots of other good books that may be more approachable. E.g. Aho and Ullman's *Data Structures and Algorithms*.

Comment: you are right, will edit it. Thank you for the answer and for the book recommendations!